# Conditional php include in wp using media queries and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I may be going about this all wrong, but here goes.... Im trying to use **JavaScript** in a **WP** theme file to do conditional **PHP** `include`s based on **CSS** media queries and pseudo-elements.

In the **CSS** I use a media query to check for mobile devices in portrait mode, add a hidden `:after` element to the body under this query with `content="mobile_portrait"` attribute.

I then wanted to go on the homepage template and use **JavaScript** like this:

```
var size = window.getComputedStyle(document.body,':after').getPropertyValue('content');
if (size == 'mobile_portrait') {
    <?php
       add_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'do_this' );
       function do_this() {
         require(CHILD_DIR.'/do_this.php');
         }
    ?>
 }
else {
    <?php
       add_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'do_the_other' );
       function do_the_other() {
         require(CHILD_DIR.'/do_the_other.php');
         }
    ?> 

}
```

It seems like WP is skipping the **JavaScript** and parsing the **PHP** because if I take out the else it just loads `do_this.php` whether the **Java** check returns true or false, if I leave the else in, it breaks the site :(

Ideas about what im doing wrong? or a better way to load **PHP** files based on media queries?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about combining PHP and JavaScript.

Comment: I don't want to offer a solution to someone who has posted a question that's a duplicate of over 50 questions. As for off topic, it doesn't literally mean off topic. The close reason "headers" are crap here.

Comment: frustrating when one is trying to learn

Answer (score 1):

PHP and Javascript cannot be used interchangeably like you are trying to do.

PHP is the renderer, it is building the output (building the Javascript)

The PHP will be run, regardless of where they are put inside a Javascript conditional like you have, as the Javascript conditionals have no bearing on them being executed.

==

Now to add a solution:

Maybe use the javascript like you have setup simply redirect to the phpfile you want to run for a given view:

```
var size = window.getComputedStyle(document.body,':after').getPropertyValue('content');
if (size == 'mobile_portrait') {
    window.location = '<?= CHILD_DIR.'/do_this.php'; ?>';
}
else {
    window.location = '<?= CHILD_DIR.'/do_the_other.php'; ?>';
}
```

So have different pages that do the necessary includes based on the media query

Comment: hmmmm. I get what you're saying about the interchangeability. Now it's behavior makes sense. The solution seems a little rough, though. I'm only trying to change one asset on the page, so to create entirely separate pages for that seems overkill. Also, it would be performance prohibitive on mobile devices having to reload a page every time they switched perspective. Thanks a ton